# Problems with publishing octave as a PDF

Tags: pdf, math, octave, publish

I am new to octave but I was told to publish particular files I want to have in PDF format as follows in the command line:

`options.format='pdf';
options.showCode = false;
publish('document1.m',options)`

document1.m had the following code:

```
%%
%Attempt 1: John Doe

%%
%Exercise 1.1

type('average.m');
```

I get the errormessage:
`'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ans = C:\Users\Documents\File`

Any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: I guess the version you installed is missing the publishing support or you missed to install some option. I do not use the windows version so I can not be sure, check again the installation setup options

Comment: You probably need to install LaTeX separately.

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate questions. It might take some time for someone to come by that knows the answer to this question. Just be patient.